# Download mp3 file on mobile phone not working

Tags: http, mobile, download, http-headers, mobile-browser

I have a webpage that offers dynamic downloading of mp3 files through mobile phones. The drill is, a dynamically generated link is sent to your mobile phone e.g http://mysvr.com/downloads/676877897/, you click the link, the server fetches the appropriate file using the link params, and submits the file back to the browser for download.

The download works pretty fine on a desktop or laptop browser i.e. it pops up the download dialog and on clicking save, proceeds to download the right file. Upto there, things are cool.

The problem comes when i try the same link on a mobile browser. i get the text prompt to download the file with a download link, but it only downloads 16kb of the file, after which I get a screaming message "Invalid file format".

When I try a direct file download link from the phone, it works fine! e.g. http://mysvr.com/ringtones/myfile.mp3, and the file plays well.

Here are the headers am sending out. is there something required by mobile browsers that is missing? Thanks in advance.

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Description: File Download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $mp3);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: Which browsers have given you this problem? What do your server logs look like for those requests? What's different compared to the requests from the desktop systems?

Comment: Sorry this code has no problem at all. The issue was with the manner in which i was expiring the links sent to the phone. Apparently my code was wrong in that execution, leading to malformed links being sent over to the phone. I have since corrected that and all is fine. Thanks samold for tryin to help. rgds.

Comment: Excellent, glad your problem is solved!